# Media player with 1> built-in delete functionality and 2> avoid duplicate entry in playlist

Tags: media-player

I am searching for a media player which offers:

1> The player should have an option to *permanently delete from the disk* a song which I am currently listening to.

I hate navigating to the exact file location on the disk and then deleting it.

2> It shouldn't allow duplicates in playlists.

Say I have song1 already in playlist1 and at a later point of time,I try to add song1 to playlist1 again - it should caution me rather than just adding a duplicate entry to the playlist.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I am currently on Windows7. If there are any android app - that would also suffice and help me a get going.